# access div in accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I can't access the div tag inside the accordion. I need to Access detDivChild.
I used

```
$("#detDivChild").html(""),
$("#accordionChild detDivChild").html(""),
$("#tab-3 accordionChild detDivChild").html("")
```

But failed.

```
 <div id="tab-3" style="clear:both;">

     <div id='accordionChild'> 

     <h3>List</h3>
     <div id="hdrDivChild"></div>
     <h3>Details</h3>
     <div id="detDivChild"></div>

     </div>


    </div
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to tell `jQuery` to select `DOM` as per `ID` (i.e adding #).

As below.

```
$("#tab-3 #accordionChild #detDivChild").html("");
```

Answer (score 0):

you're trying to access the selector accordionChild as if it were a tag.  accordionChild is written as the id of the tag you're trying to access.  change to this:

```
$("#accordionChild #detDivChild").html("")
```

similarly for

```
$("#tab-3 #accordionChild #detDivChild").html("")
```